# How would I use BeautifulSoup to parse the text from this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<h6 class="my-0 px-2 text-light py-1 text-truncate" title="TEST" style="background-color: rgb(48, 54, 60); --darkreader-inline-bgcolor:#2b3033;" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor="">TEST</h6>
```

I'm trying to get the string 'TEST' and there are multiple of these classes with different titles/strings (e.g TEST1, TEST2, so-fourth), I tried using soup.find and have no luck -- what am I doing wrong?

```
result = soup.find('div',{'class':'my-0 px-2 text-light py-1 text-truncate'})
print(result.text)
```

Outputs 'None'

Comment: The first argument for `soup.find` is the tag, which is your case should be `'h6'` not `'div'`

Comment: @Tim That works! Thanks a lot however how would I go about getting all of the same classes' text (at the moment it only gives the first one it finds)

Comment: Sorry, missed that. BeautifulSoup has a `find_all()` function which will return a list with every match (I think - or it might return some kind of generator). I think its function signature is the same, but you'll have to check the documentation 

Comment: Or it might be `findall()` (without the underscore) - I can never remember...

Answer (score 3):

```
result = soup.find('h6',{'class':'my-0 px-2 text-light py-1 text-truncate'})
print(result.text)
```

[image]